# PHP не видит форму

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, база-данных

Подключение к базе подключается 101%, поскольку текст `echo "<a href='index.php'> back <a/>";` мне  "приходит" на стр. Но в PHP форма не "приходит".

```
fn    = document.getElementById('fn').value;
ln    = document.getElementById('ln').value;
```

`AJAX` видит их пустыми, хотя поля заполнены. Ошибок не выбивает.

Возможно я догадываюсь в чем проблема, форма приходит в PHP -> идет проверка ->
   `if ( $name == '' && $last_name == '' ) { /***/ }` видит их пустые,  **и конец.**

Вся проблема в `VALUE` для AJAX они пустые, почему?

Помогите, спасибо!

```
  <form action="" method="post" id="reg">
       <input type="text"   name="First"  id="fn"  value="">
       <input type="text"   name="Last"   id="ln"  value="">
       <input type="submit" name="post_user" onclick="add_ajax_rquest()" value="Add" >
    </form>
    <p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
```

---

```
<?php 

require_once('connect.php');
echo "<a href='index.php'> back <a/>";

//add to db users
if(isset($_POST['post_user'])){

    $name      = $_POST['First'];
    $last_name = $_POST['Last'];    

    echo $name;
    echo $last_name;

    if ( $name == '' && $last_name == '' ) {
            echo "Fields name is not filing!";
    } else {

        $get_id_user   = 'SELECT MAX(id) FROM users';
        $result_id_user = mysqli_query( $con, $get_id_user );
        $users_id       = mysqli_fetch_array( $result_id_user );

        $queryInsertName   = 
               "INSERT INTO 
                    users ( `user_first_name`, 
                            `user_last_name` ) 
                VALUES ( '$name', '$last_name' )";

        $resultName  = mysqli_query($con, $queryInsertName);
    }
}

?>
```

---

```
function add_ajax_rquest() {
  var  fn    = document.getElementById('fn').value;
  var  ln    = document.getElementById('ln').value;
  var  phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;

  var request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

  request.open("POST", 'regist.php', true);

  request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  request.send(fn, ln, phone); 

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML = request.responseText;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**ajax_POST_UTF8.js**

```js
function createXMLHttp() {
        if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") { // для браузеров аля Mozilla
            return new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // для Internet Explorer (all versions) 
            var aVersions = [
                "MSXML2.XMLHttp.5.0",
                "MSXML2.XMLHttp.4.0",
                "MSXML2.XMLHttp.3.0",
                "MSXML2.XMLHttp",
                "Microsoft.XMLHttp"
            ];
            for (var i = 0; i < aVersions.length; i++) {
                try {
                    var oXmlHttp = new ActiveXObject(aVersions[i]);
                    return oXmlHttp;
                } catch (oError) {}
            }
            throw new Error("Невозможно создать объект XMLHttp.");
        }
    }
// фукнция Автоматической упаковки формы любой сложности
function getRequestBody(oForm) {
    var aParams = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < oForm.elements.length; i++) {
        var sParam = encodeURIComponent(oForm.elements[i].name);
        sParam += "=";
        sParam += encodeURIComponent(oForm.elements[i].value);
        aParams.push(sParam);
    }
    return aParams.join("&");
}
// функция Ajax POST
function postAjax(url, oForm, callback) { 
    // создаем Объект
    var oXmlHttp = createXMLHttp();
    // получение данных с формы
    var sBody = getRequestBody(oForm);
    // подготовка, объявление заголовков
    oXmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
    oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // описание функции, которая будет вызвана, когда придет ответ от сервера
    oXmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (oXmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (oXmlHttp.status == 200) {
                callback(oXmlHttp.responseText);
            } else {
                callback('error' + oXmlHttp.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    // отправка запроса, sBody - строка данных с формы
    oXmlHttp.send(sBody);
}
```

**form_post.html**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' src='ajax_POST_UTF8.js'></script>
    <script>
        function showResult(d) {
            document.getElementById('displayText').innerHTML = d;
        }
 
        function do_post_ajax() {
            postAjax('pro_post.php', document.forms[0], showResult);
        }
    </script>
    <form>
        Проверка POST
        <br>напишите яблоко<br>
        <input type=text name=ge1>
        <br>напишите огурец<br>
        <input type=text name=ge2><br>
    </form>
    <a href="JavaScript:do_post_ajax()">проверить POST</a>
        <div id="displayText"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**pro_post.php**

```html
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
if (!empty($_POST["ge1"])) {
    print '<b>' . $_POST["ge1"] . '</b> пришло<br>';
} else {
    echo 'нет значения';
}
if (!empty($_POST["ge2"])) {
    print '<b>' . $_POST["ge2"] . '</b> пришло<br>';
} else {
    echo 'нет значения';
}
```